# Select with values in the IN clause not returning actual values

Tags: mysql

In the below query

```
mysql> select
    ->     what_to_wear_under,
    -> (select group_concat(value) from eav_attribute_option_value where option_id in (what_to_wear_under) and store_id = 1  ) as what_to_wear_under
    -> from
    -> catalog_product_flat_1 where brief_coverage is not null and brief_coverage > 0 limit 1\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
what_to_wear_under: 2028,2031,2032
what_to_wear_under: Churidar Kurtas
1 row in set, 2 warnings (0.00 sec)
```

what_to_wear_under is having three values when I use **option_id in (what_to_wear_under)** its giving value for only one id.

but If I use values directly its returns values correctly

```
mysql> select     what_to_wear_under, (select group_concat(value) from eav_attribute_option_value where option_id in (2028,2031,2032) and store_id = 1  ) as what_to_wear_under from  catalog_product_flat_1 where brief_coverage is not null and brief_coverage > 0 limit 1\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
what_to_wear_under: 2028,2031,2032
what_to_wear_under: Churidar Kurtas,Denims,Dresses
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Can you please help how we can modify query one to get three values?

Comment: you should use prepare query

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't compare in to a column like this, it will consider him as 1 value no matter he contains values separated by commas.

You can use like for this(I'm not sure about mysql syntax so maybe u'll have to adjust it with the concat):

```
select
->     what_to_wear_under,
-> (select group_concat(value) from eav_attribute_option_value where  what_to_wear_under like concat('%',option_id,'%') and store_id = 1  ) as what_to_wear_under
-> from
-> catalog_product_flat_1 where brief_coverage is not null and brief_coverage > 0 limit 1\G
```

Comment: Thanks, but now its returning 5 values what_to_wear_under: Churidar Kurtas,Denims,Dresses,Sports Bra,T-Shirt Bra
Expected is what_to_wear_under: Churidar Kurtas,Denims,Dresses